# How to map dictionary in react class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

**Hello, community! Hope you all are good.**

I was trying to map a dictionary in my class component but it gives me a hooks error.
I wanted to create several cards with different information so that I approached like this but now it shows me the Hooks error and I tried many things and find out that this piece of code has an error but can't figure out what please help me.

My code is below

```
export class AskModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      modalState: true,
      services: {
        "Employement": [
          "/employement",
          "/images/humhai-static-data/employment.jpg",
          "This para is for Employement",
          "text-dark"
        ],
        "Business opportunity": [
          "/self-employement",
          "/images/humhai-static-data/buisness-opportunity.jpg",
          "This para is for Self Employement",
          "text-dark"
        ],
        "Covid Helpdesk": [
          "../covid-helpline",
          "/images/humhai-static-data/covid-helpdesk.jpg",
          "This para is for Covid help desk",
          "text-danger"
        ],
        "Volunteer": [
          "../covid-helpline/volunteer",
          "/images/humhai-static-data/volunteer.jpg",
          "This para is for Volunteer",
          "text-dark"
        ],
      },
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);

  }
  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      modalState: !this.state.modalState
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {Object.keys(this.state.services).map(name => (
          <MDBCol md="3" size="6" className="mx-auto my-2">
            <MDBCard className="border rounded h-100 z-depth-5" color={this.state.services[name][3]}>
              <Link to={this.state.services[name][0]} onClick={this.toggle} className={this.state.services[name][3]}>
                <MDBCardImage className="img-fluid" src={this.state.services[name][1]} />
                <MDBCardBody>
                  <MDBCardTitle><i className="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> {name}</MDBCardTitle>
                  <div className="d-none d-lg-block">
                    <hr />
                    <MDBCardText>
                      <p>{this.state.services[name][2]}</p>
                    </MDBCardText>
                  </div>
                </MDBCardBody>
              </Link>
            </MDBCard>
          </MDBCol>
        ))
        }
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What you say is impossible. There is no hook in the code. And also, hooks cannot be used in class components., you will need to convert it to a function component first

Comment: Can you show me how? I just started working in react JS and a noobie @Tyblitz

Comment: There seems to be no problem at all. Are you using any library?
I tried it on codesandbox and it's working just fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-snowflake-0gsqx?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is because you are doing a map on `this.state.services` and it ideally shouldn't even be related to `hooks` as you are not using them here in this component.

If you check your **state** object, `this.state.services` would return an `object` and not an array. So, if you could revisit your code and check the same.
Also, the way you have created the **services** object might not be the best way, just putting a snippet below if it helps as to how you can make it more scalabale.

```js
const services = [
  { name: "Employment", route: "/employment", image: "path/to/image.jpg", text: "Text", mode: "dark mode" }, // and so on
]
```

Comment: Thanks, @jaybhatt now I got it what I was doing wrong